# Disable fax in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin

How do I disable the fax field for customers? (preferrably using the admin, not removing code)

Comment: From Admin it's difficult. Can do with DB?

Comment: How do you mean? Removing tables in the database?

Comment: Just disable that field from Database Table

Comment: I'd rather find another way to be honest. If the webshop owner wants to enable the fax again, I don't want to mess in the database. I'd prefer a code solution more than a database solution

Comment: then create a module that triggers enable/disable in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would never recommend writing a module to hide an attribute, in most cases this can be done via the admin panel. Here is how to disable fax via the admin panel.

**This is for Magento EE 2.1.1**

1. Goto `Stores - Attributes - Customer Address`
2. Click on the attribute fax and set `use in customer segment` to no

**This is for Magento CE 2.0.7**

1. Goto Stores - Configuration - Customers - Customer Configuration
2. Expand Address Templates group and remove `{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var
   fax}}{{/depend}}` from all the text boxes.

> I've only specified these versions because thats the ones I tested on.

Comment: Is this a Magento 2 solution? Because I can't find 'attributes' under 'stores'

Comment: Yes, this is a Magento solution. What version of Magento are you running?

Comment: I'm currently running 2.0.7.

Comment: Yes you should have it, go to stores and there should be a a link called Customer Address under the label attributes

Comment: See screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq0BY.png

Comment: It seems that in 2.0.7., under the label Attributes, there is only 'product', 'Attribute Set' and 'Rating'

Comment: Enterprise or Community?

Comment: Community edition

Comment: Hmm thats why, let me check on my community setup.

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen check updated answer

Comment: @André Ferraz, I tried your answer which successfully removed the fax but but resulted in 'place order' button doing nothing when clicked during a test order after removing {{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var
fax}}{{/depend}} from all the text boxes. Please tell me what needs to done.

Comment: @André Ferraz, strange that these steps when followed a few weeks ago removed the fax field from the checkout page. For some reason, I rolled the change made back, and now want to remove it again by following the same steps but it is not taking any effect. The version is CE 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your `style.css` and it will remove the Fax field only from your Checkout page in frontend.

> .checkout-index-index .field[name="shippingAddress.fax"] { display:
>   none; }

Comment: is this for Magento 2?

Comment: It is not working

Answer (score 0):

One can remove the Fax field from the Magento checkout Page by setting `Show Fax to No` as seen in the screenshot below. My store is on Magento CE 2.3.4

[image]